# Consumir servicio rest de c# desde Spring Boot

Tags: java, c#, spring-boot

Necesito un ejemplo o al menos recomendaciones sobre como llamar rest apis de c# usando Spring Boot.
Por ejemplo: Este es el metodo C# al cual pretendo hacer la llamada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí viene un ejemplo completo y funcional: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: En lugar de añadir una nueva pregunta, lo que deberías haber hecho es editar tu anterior pregunta para traducirla.